# Reload Parent Fragment on Tab Selection

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a parent fragment which has a header view with tab layout & view pager.
I have 2 different views to be shown

view1 = headerView1 & TabLayout1 with ViewPager1

view2 = headerView2 & TabLayout2 with ViewPager2

when the fragment is launched I want to show view1 by default. On item click of a button in tabLayout of view1 I have to show the view2 and hide view1.

I am not able to figure out how to handle this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? Can you post any code snippet? If I understand correctly, you have your `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in your parent fragment. Attach a `OnTabSelectedListener` to your TabLayout, and override `onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)` method.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
   //Change your viewpager pages here.
}
```

If you want to update your parent fragment from your `View1` or `View2` fragment, use the `getParentFragment()` method on your child fragments.

```
((YourParentFragment) getParentFragment()).doTask();
```

In your parent fragment,

```
public void doTask()
{
    //Do your refreshing here.
    //Or switch your pages in Viewpager.
}
```

Please post some code. That will get you better answers.